# What is causing my Jackson ObjectMapper serialization to output invalid JSON (no quotes around keys)?

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I see a lot of questions about wanting to drop the quotes around keys *intentionally*, but I have the opposite problem: I'm getting invalid JSON and don't know why. This is how my ObjectMapper is being created:

```
  @VisibleForTesting
  public static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper()
      .registerModule(new JodaModule())
      .registerModule(new GuavaModule())
      .registerModule(new AutoMatterModule())
      .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
      .registerModule(new ProtobufModule())
      .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
      .configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
      .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false)
      .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
      .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

Those who *want* to drop quotes have to set these config items:

```
mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES, false);
mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
```

But as you can see, I'm not setting those config items. Are one of the modules or serialization features setting one of those config items by side-effect?

---

**Edit**

I've figured out how to inspect my `OBJECT_MAPPER`'s configuration after construction by inserting a breakpoint then using the expression evaluator (calculator symbol on the debugger pane, for those wanting to repeat these steps):

[image]

[image]

So, there appears to be no overriding of config. Can a module perhaps override the config entirely?

---

**Edit 2**

On @EugenCovaci's request, the object being serialized is actually an interface that autogenerates getters and setters (similar library to AutoMapper):

```
import io.norberg.automatter.AutoMatter;

@AutoMatter
public interface CreativeData {
  UUID id();
  DateTime created();
  String name();
  String creativeType();
  String status();
  String title();
  AssetData asset();
  List<AssetData> companions();
  Optional<String> maybeRejectReason();
}
```

Comment: I'm using your `OBJECT_MAPPER` and I get this valid output: `{"firstname":"foo","transaction_amount":1.0}`. Can you post the Java class that produces wrong output?

Comment: @EugenCovaci - Sure, added it at the bottom. Thanks for trying it out.

Comment: Here is my output (without AssetData fields): `{"id":"01771c73-ded4-4409-85ac-6e0cb09d3e64","created":"2018-12-01T06:38:12.891Z","name":"boo","creativeType":"foo","status":"bar","title":"title","maybeRejectReason":null}` It looks valid.

Comment: @EugenCovaci - Huh, and that's with all the modules as well?

Comment: Yes ...........

Comment: @EugenCovaci - Okay, let me step through the debugger more deeply later today. Maybe an ObjectMapper is getting swapped, or something is being intercepted before going over HTTP. Thank you!